# Ethereum how to create account on parity hosted on Kovan network?

Tags: parity, web3.py

I have a parity node hosted on kovan network.
How to create account using web3py?
I used web3.personal.newAccount()=>which is giving error as no method found.

What are the api's available for parity?

Comment: Have you enabled the personal API on the node you are connected to?

Comment: @RaghavSood yes I have enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `personal` module is not standardized across clients. `parity` supports a different API than `geth`. Some alternatives for creating an account:

1. Use [locally managed keys](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html), OR
2. [Create the accounts on the parity node](https://wiki.parity.io/CLI-Sub-commands#account-new) using the CLI

#### Local keys

```
>>> my_account = w3.eth.account.create('add something random here to improve key generation')
>>> transaction = {
...     'to': '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
...     'value': 1000000000,
...     'gas': 2000000,
...     'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
...     'nonce': 0,
...     'chainId': 1
... }
>>> signed = my_account.signTransaction(transaction)
>>> w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

#### Parity CLI

> ```
> parity --chain kovan account new
> Loading config file from users.toml
> Please note that password is NOT RECOVERABLE.
> Type password: 
> Repeat password:
> 0x66a4b6f39b4c3e7203ab9caeecbad58d8f29b046
> ```

Comment: The account created using w3.eth.account.create is not available in parity node..and the 'to' key in transaction is standard?

Comment: Right, when using local keys, all signing would have to happen locally in python. The account would never be added to your parity node. If you must have the account in your node, then try the Parity CLI option.

Comment: It would be nice to add a 3rd option which would be to load a previously existing account into web3py

Comment: I see where you're going, but I think it's OT for this particular question, and believe that question is asked/answered elsewhere.